# Feynman Diagrams for $\phi^{4}$ theory, up to order $g^2$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

I'm considering $\phi^4$ theory with the action $S[\phi] = S_{\mathrm{FREE}}[\phi] + \frac{g}{4!} \int d^{4}x \ \phi(x)^4$.

I'm supposed to come up with the Feynman diagrams up to order $g^2$ for the 2-point and 4-point correlation functions.

It's not necessarily hard, it's just extremely tedious and I'm worried I'm missing some diagrams (I think there are 21 diagrams at order $g^2$ for the four-point function, for example. This is headache to make sure I've got everything down correctly)

My question is, is there a resource that lists off the Feynman diagrams up to order $g^2$? It's easy for me to find up to order $g^1$ (but not higher than that).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [Critical Properties of $\phi^4$ Theories](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/kleiner_reb8/psfiles/phi4.pdf), chapter 3: Feynman Diagrams. For example,

[image]

and

[image]